# Haskell why is [fst,snd] :: [(a,a) -> a]

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and am wondering why

```
[fst,snd] :: [(a,a) -> a]
```

I originally wrote

```
[fst,snd] :: [(a,b) -> a, (c, d) -> d]
```

I cannot understand why it is the way it is; could someone please explain?

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand why `["abc", "def"] :: [String]`?

Comment: Yes but what is confusing me is `(fst, snd) :: ((a, b) -> a, (a1, b1) -> b1)`, why is it not the same for lists?

Comment: Ok I get it now, a list can only have the same type in it, so whether it is either first or second it is still a? Is this a correct explanation?

Comment: @something Yes, lists are _homogeneous_, meaning that they can contain only elements of the same type. Here, the types `fst::(a,b)->a` and `snd::(a,b)->b` are specialized to a _common type_, so that they can be put together in the same list. Such common type occurs when `a=b`, so GHC infers that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The point is that lists, in Haskell, are a homogeneous data structure (of course, you can have heterogeneous lists, but it is another story). So, when you use polymorphic functions as lists elements they should have the same type.

In your case you are using `fst :: (a , b) -> a` and `snd :: (a, b) -> b` as list elements so, they **must** have the same type. To ensure the sameness of these types, type inference resort to first-order unification. Unifying

```
 (a , b) -> a
```

and

```
 (a , b) -> b
```

we notice that the following substitution make these types equal is

```
 [b +-> a] -- means substitute occurrences of b for a
```

Applying it to both types, we get

```
 (a,a) -> a
```

as Haskell is telling you.

Comment: Thanks, this has clarified it alot for me.